# Symfony Form and different validation groups

Tags: symfony, symfony-validator

I have a form called UserType, which is used in my controller when creating a new user:

```
$newUser = new User();
$form = $this->createForm(UserType::class, $newUser);
$form->submit($request->request->all());
```

Now, I would like to also have an update route where a form is used. The form might be a different one, since some properties is not possible to change after creation. Because of this, I would also like different validations in the Entity. How do I pass different validation groups through the form in my controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the Option Resolver You can pass the group name validation as an option and get It in the UserType

```
$newUser = new User();
$form = $this->createForm(UserType::class, $newUser, ['validation'=>'your_validation_group_name']);
$form->submit($request->request->all());
```

and in the `UserType`

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('username', TextType::class, [
                'validation'=> $options['validation'] //contains your_validation_group_name 
            ])
        ;
    }
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
        {
            $resolver->setDefaults(array(
                'validation' => ''
            ));
        }
```